# Trying to insert into Table A and link Table B and C but add to all if not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables:

```
Table A: 
  LogID (unique identifier), 
  UserID (bigint), 
  LogDate (date/time), 
  LogEventID (int), 
  IPID (varchar(36)), 
  UserAgentID (varchar(36))

Table B: 
  IPID (unique identifier), 
  IPAddress (varchar(255))

Table C: 
  UserAgentID (unique identifier), 
  UserAgent (varchar(255))

Table D: 
  LogEventID (int), 
  LogEvent (varchar(255))
```

I am trying to write the to `Table A` but need to check `Table B`, `Table C` and `Table D` contain data so I can link them. If they don’t contain any data, I would need to create some. Some of the tables may contain data, sometimes none of them may.

Pretty much everything, really struggling

Comment: Sorry, it’s MsSQL

Comment: Still..remains similar.google Foreign keys in MSSQL or SQL

Comment: Create a procedure which first tries to insert into B,C,D with `RETURNIG` clause and if no raw inserted (raw already exists), selects id. Being 3 ids collected, insert into A. Declare IPAddress, UserAgent , LogEvent UNIQUE

Comment: Add some sample data from B,C,D and the logic you wants to check before you insert into A.

Answer (score 0):

first, you do a insert into table B, C, D `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

example

```
INSERT INTO TableB (IPID, IPAddress) 
SELECT @IPPD, @IPAddress
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   TableB x
           WHERE  x.IPID = @IPID
       )
```

then you insert into table A

```
 INSERT INTO TableA ( . . . )
 SELECT . . .
```

Comment: That’s pretty much what I am currently doing, but was hoping to wrap it all up into one sql script

Comment: what do you mean by `wrap it up` ? Are you referring to `Stored Procedure` ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't let you modify multiple tables in a single statement, so you cannot do this with a single statement.

What can you do?

1. You can wrap the multiple statements in a single transaction, if your goal is to modify the database only once.
2. You can write the multiple statements in stored procedure.
3. What you really probably want is a view with `insert` triggers on the view.  You can define a view that is the join of the tables with the values from the reference tables.  An `insert` trigger can then check if the values exist and replace them with the appropriate ids.  Or, insert into the appropriate table.

The third option does exactly what you want.  I find that it is a bit of trouble to maintain triggers, so for an application, I would prefer wrapping the logic in a stored procedure.